# Full disk encryption (and decrypt on boot) for existing Debian installation (bookworm)

Tags: debian, luks, disk-encryption

I have an existing Debian system and there is a need to encrypt the disk at rest. Searching online (and here) I see that the only way to do it is to do a fresh installation, this time with LUKS on. I have about 900 MB (out of 1TB) unallocated. Is there any viable alternative here (and ideally without LVM)?

Comment: You could encrypt a single directory (e.g., user home dir) rather than the whole filesystem.  Full disk encryption requires reformatting, and automatic unlock at boot requires (probably) TPM.

Comment: Thats a nice tip. Encrypting my home drive is sufficient. Do I still use LUKS or are there easier alternatives?

Comment: I think LUKS requires full disk encryption and vice versa.  Note that full disk encryption is the only way (short of physical measures) to ensure your OS isn't tampered with.

Comment: I mostly care about "machine is stolen, who can access my data" to be honest. Do you think it is the best choice or are there better alternatives?

Comment: For that, encrypting your home dir or even better, a single directory berried in your home dir is probably fine, but use a very strong password and if possible a large machine generated key on separate hardware that doesn't stay with the laptop, like a usb key on your keychain or soemthing.

Comment: There is `cryptsetup reencrypt --encrypt` but it comes with a lot of warnings. Like the manpage states, *ALWAYS BE SURE YOU HAVE RELIABLE BACKUP BEFORE USING THIS*. And even if it works, you'll have to fix up your fstab/crypttab/initramfs/bootloader/...

Comment: Thanks for the hints folks, I will give cryptsetup a try. Else format again